# What is the difference between testRPC and geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, testrpc

I wonder what is the difference between testRPC and geth (on private network) because, they both can create:

- blockchains
- nodes
- accounts

The "only" difference I see, is that the testRPC has almost unlimited Ether, which makes the mining process unnecessary.

Maybe is there a link between geth and the testRPC? I mean applying some functions implented in geth could be applied on a testRPC network?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 15):

Test RPC is a client for testing:

> testrpc is a Node.js based Ethereum client for testing and
>   development. It uses ethereumjs to simulate full client behavior and
>   make developing Ethereum applications much faster. It also includes
>   all popular RPC functions and features (like events) and can be run
>   deterministically to make development a breeze.

While Geth is a full client in GO Language that you can use to connect to the real chain or start your own testnet server.

> geth is the command line interface for running a full ethereum
>   node implemented in Go. It is the main deliverable of the Frontier
>   Release.

Of course, some succeed tests in testRPC cases can be transfered to geth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
But I still miss something:
What is the difference between testRPC and a private testnet server with go/geth?

Comment: Testrpc only simulate the chain but is not one.

Comment: I also believe transactions get mined right away on TestRPC while on a test blockchain with geth, it takes a bit more time to mine the transaction, so it could be a drag on development, in a sense.

Comment: Also, in addition to what @NicolasMassart, you wouldn't test on TestRPC only before deploying to mainnet, it would be wise to test on geth's test blockchain as well prior to doing so.

Comment: @NYCTechEngineer absolutely. Testrpc is really just for the development phase. Testing on the official testnet or on a private net it best practice to fully validate your contract.

Comment: I guess in summary, development -> testrpc, alpha test -> geth or using Infura nodes